# iOS and Web-app for flashcard/testing

Tags: gratis, web-apps, ios, flashcard

I am looking for a flashcard/tester app for iOS, and the web.

I'm going to use it for learning languages, but it could be used for anything.

It basically needs to take in 2 things, for example, English and German words/phrases.

The app should then allow me to test myself on these, either way (like switching sides on a flashcard), by typing, looking at virtual flashcards, or *hearing* the things. If there are 'games' that help you learn the stuff, even better!

To summarise (and add a few points):

- free iOS and web app (probably need to register)
- supports languages (audio pronunciation for languages, especially German and English)
- supports tests (type in the opposite language, say English to German)
- supports typos (preferably with a button saying 'typo' or similar. Definitely not automatically thinking it's a typo)
- supports case sensitivity *toggle* (German requires capital first letter for nouns, but for something that's not a language, I don't care about capitals, so I shld be able to turn the feature on or off)
- supports 'I don't know' to show me the answer if I don't know it
- hopefully statistics on games/tests, preferably testing me more frequently on things I don't know
- hopefully a way to just look at the words/phrases (in flashcard form, or list form - anything!)
- hopefully speed 'games' or similar to aid learning

I know these are a lot of strict requirements, but only the first 6 are required - I'm sure there are many apps to do this, but I'm looking for a recommendation based on experience so I know whether it works for them or not :)

Comment: Related: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/504/6834

Comment: @Timmy Does look related, but looks like I'm asking for the complete opposite! I want to be tested whereas the other asker didn't :)

Comment: Indeed. But the answer for that question does satisfy some of your requirements, and would help if someone is looking for something similar

Comment: @Timmy Tested it out... it isn't exactly what I was thinking of, although it is definitely powerful in terms of when it asks you specific words. I think this is a possible backup choice if nobody else answers this question, but I'm sure there are people who are looking for a similar type of app, so, I'll wait. I've upvoted that question and answer anyway, as they are both very good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Quizlet.com](http://quizlet.com/) looks perfect for me!:

- free iOS app, Android app, web app
- supports audio pronunciation for German and French
- supports tests - 'Learn' mode
- allows you to override it in case you had a typo
- if you don't know the answer, just leave the space blank and it makes you type it out again
- I think it tests you more frequently on unknown words - it feels like it does anyway!
- view as flashcards/list
- 'games' - although I don't think they help *me* learn - they might help you!

But, it doesn't support toggling capital letters.

You need to register for a free account. You can also share 'sets' with other people with an account. Or make 'classes' for a group of people.